# Is it convenient or are you convenient? - How to use the word 'convenient'?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, sentence-usage

I looked upon some dictionaries for the adjective *convenient* and studied some examples. However, I did not get it. Whilst most of the example sentences use this adjective for *a non-living thing,* I wonder whether or not this adjective can be used to modify a person.

Which one should I say?

> 1. Is it convenient for you to help me?
> 2. Are you convenient to help me?
> 3. Is it convenient to help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a look at a dictionary? They usually have example sentences. Can you find anything that helps [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/convenient?q=convenient) or [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/convenient)? After you've had a look at those, you could edit your question and tell us if you think your sentences are right or wrong.

Comment: I agree that this question could be greatly improved, particularly if you first explained what you were trying to say (perhaps with a scenario of sorts). I can see where this would be a very tricky word for a learner to use, so I'd like the question to stay open. Study how [Yoichi](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please/465#465) asks questions, and try to make this something more than a multiple choice question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most of the cases, the adjective *convenient* is *not used* with a person. Having said this, the first and third sentences are okay whereas the remaining one does not sound grammatical.

It's important to note that you can *use convenient* with human but then it'll be a bit offensive. Suppose if you call some woman as a *convenient woman* it means she's readily available to have fun with.

In other words, if a person is *a convenient person*, one can take advantage of. Probably, that is because one can use them as a convenience.

Comment: oh... I guess sometimes it can be an "compliment" because maybe some very weird people would be proud of that? Thanks for the answer anyway!

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use the first one. It seems sound to me.

> Is it convenient for you to help me?

Comment: The second one isn't correct.

Comment: The second one isn't correct in Br or US English. It is a very common mistake among Asian students.